# What is the belly pod on this Beech A200 Super King Air?

Tags: military, equipment

In this photo of N46L, a Beech A200 Super King Air owned by Dynamic Aviation, there is a large pod attached to the belly with what looks like two largish ports or windows on the underside.  What is it, exactly?  It looks similar to a synthetic aperture radar pod or video surveillance package, but I was curious if anyone could ID it precisely.

[image: Pod on underside of King Air]

The full photo is available at http://www.jetphotos.net/viewphoto_new.php?id=7118680.

Comment: Looking at the full photo, it appears there's also a non-standard installation on the belly aft of the pod and possibly something other than a pitot tube on the right upper part of the nose.

Comment: Good catch--if anyone knows what those are I'd like to know!

Answer (score 22, accepted):

### Short answer

It seems to be a US Army CEASAR pod, a communication intercepting and jamming system for electronic warfare, which has been flown in Iraq and Afghanistan. CEASAR is derived from AN/ALQ-227 EA used by US Navy on the [EA-18G Growler](http://www.naval-technology.com/projects/ea-18g-growler/).

The aircraft is equipped with missile detection and countermeasures. Two sensors are below the cockpit windscreen, two other on the aft fuselage. The chaff is released by a dispenser aft of the pod.

N40R is N46L's sister aircraft, and it also carries a CEASAR pod. The A200 variant used may be a C12-A or a C-12C (this is the model number visible on N40R fuselage). They are also known as *Huron* and *HC-12*.

High definition photo of N46R:

[image: High definition photo of N46R]
<sup>Photo by [Keith Newsome](http://s261.photobucket.com/user/keithnewsome/profile/) on photobucket ([source](http://s261.photobucket.com/user/keithnewsome/media/DSC_3106.jpg.html))</sup>

Detailed answer below.

---

### About CEASAR

From [Stars and Stripes](http://www.stripes.com/news/new-technology-can-jam-intercept-insurgent-transmissions-1.174720#):

> The CEASAR, which stands for communications electronic attack with
> surveillance and reconnaissance, is a rectangular metal box that holds
> technology capable of both knocking out cell phones and radios and
> intercepting transmissions, while an electronic warfare officer
> onboard speaks directly to troops on the ground. It’s precise enough
> to cover friendly soldiers while jamming insurgents, but not knocking
> out communications for an entire village near a given operation.

[image: Air crew disembarking the aircraft]

From [matthewaid.com](http://www.matthewaid.com/post/84445892216/contractors-continue-flying-ceasar-sigint-aircraft):

> *Contractors Continue Flying CEASAR SIGINT Aircraft in Afghanistan*
>
> The CEASAR system mounted in these contractor-owned and
> government-operated (COGO) aircraft is based on the Raytheon
> AN/ALQ-227 EA system as fitted to the US Navy’s (USN’s) Boeing EA-18G
> Growler electronic warfare (EW) aircraft. It is designed to provide
> both a communications jamming and an intercept/monitoring capability.

[image: Manoeuvring aircraft]

### CEASAR UAV replacement

Flying CEASAR on a modified A200 was already very much cheaper than using a pod on a fighter. However like for other functions, military are looking at using unmanned aircraft. The NERO pod has been designed for this purpose.

From [Defense Systems](https://defensesystems.com/articles/2014/07/17/army-nero-electronic-warfare-drones.aspx):

> *NERO jams aboard a drone in Army test*
>
> The Army recently tested a jammer called the Networked Electronic
> Warfare Remotely Operated, or NERO, attached to a Gray Eagle unmanned
> combat aircraft at the Great Salt Lake Desert at Dugway Proving
> Ground, Utah.

[image: NERO drone on the ground]

---

### Missile Warning System AN/AAR-47

Closer view (N40R):

[image: Aircraft cockpit exterior, showing the sensor stalks]

It detects infrared or radio sensing from a missile and commands a response, e.g. release of chaff or flare using the countermeasures dispensing system aft of the pod.

Two other sensors are located [on the aft fuselage](http://www.jetphotos.net/viewphoto_new.php?id=7118680).

Sensor detail on another aircraft:

[image: Close-up of sensor]
([source](http://vpk.name/news/127491_ssha_postavyat_indii_stancii_preduprezhdeniya_o_raketnom_napadenii.html))

---

### About the aircraft

From [FAA](http://fsims.faa.gov/PICDetail.aspx?docId=FSB%20BE-200), King Air A200, CN `BC-1` thru `BC-61` are variant C-12A used by US Army.

From [JetPhotos.net](http://jetphotos.net/showphotos.php?regsearch=N46L) this aircraft is used under call-sign Grizzly 23:

> Registration: N46L
> CN: BC-56
> 'Grizzly 23' taxies for departure to Wick.this is one of a number of
> aircraft owned by Dynamic that operate on behalf of the US Army.

There are two C-12 aircraft equipped with CEASAR. The other is registered N40R, with call-sign *Grizzly 12*:

[image: N46L and N40R on the ground]
([source](http://www.fightercontrol.co.uk/forum/viewtopic.php?f=16&p=472631))

Huron are [seconded or being replaced by Dash 8](http://www.militaryaerospace.com/articles/2013/11/army-dash8-comint.html).

Comment: Excellent job tracking that down, thanks!

Comment: Excellent answer yet again!  In my opinion, one of the best on this site!